# Why is ((ans != 'N') || (ans != 'Y')) always true?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to prompt the user to spin again and my "while" expression is always coming back as false... Anyone have any ideas?

```
reSpin = false;
if (reSpin == false){
    System.out.println("Would you like to spin again? Y/N");
    char ans = in.next().charAt(0);
   if (ans == 'Y'){
       reSpin =true;

   }else if (ans == 'N'){
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
   }else {
       while ((ans != 'N') || (ans != 'Y')) {
           System.out.println("Invalid answer, please only enter Y/N");
           System.out.println("Would you like to spin again? Y/N");
           ans = in.next().charAt(0);
       }
   }


}
```

Comment: Is `Y` == `N`? Then if `ans` is `Y`, it is not equal to `N`. What about `N` == `Y`? If `ans` is `N` it is not `Y`. Thus, no letter can satisfy both conditions simultaneously. Also, if you apply [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) then your expression could be written as `((ans == 'N') && (ans == 'Y'))` which is probably clearer.

Comment: Thanks you @ElliottFrisch for the mention of DeMorgan! This is the second question I have seen today that could have been solved with these simple rules!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use:

```
   while ((ans != 'N') && (ans != 'Y')) {
```

That checks to see that `ans` is not N *and* not Y. If you use `||` (or) there, then it will check to see that `ans` is either not N, or not Y (which is true for any value of `ans`).

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple: According to your comparison, `ans` would have to be `Y` and `N` at the same time.

Comment: i know. luckily were working with computers here: either yes **or** no.

Answer (score 2):

`||` returns true if *either one* of the expressions on either side is true.

If `ans` is `Y`, then `ans != 'N'` is true, so the whole expression `(ans != 'N') || (ans != 'Y')` is true.  If `ans` is `N`, then `ans != 'Y'` is true, so the whole expression is true.

You want `(ans != 'N') && (ans != 'Y')`, which says "`ans` is not `'N'` *and* `ans` is also not `'Y'`."

Answer (score 1):

`ans` cannot be both 'N' and 'Y' at the same time, so it is always either not equal to 'N' or not equal to 'Y'. You might want to change it to:

```
while ((ans != 'N') && (ans != 'Y'))
```

This makes sure that it is both not equal to 'N' and not equal to 'Y'.